# how to install Java on Linux?

Tags: java

Ηow to install Java on Linux so that Ι can connect to JOSM?

Comment: tar (child): -/Downloads/jdk-8u231-linux-x64.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory

Comment: Which Linux are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to have downloaded the oracle package in the "Downloads" folder ?

If so, you can do:

```
tar -xzvf Downloads/jdk-8u231-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

You can find more informations here:
https://www.ethicalhackx.com/install-java-jdk-kali-linux/
https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?41-Installing-Java-on-Kali-Linux